# Aspnetcore Swagger always redirecting and I can't access other files through url

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, swagger, azure-web-app-service

I publish to Microsoft Azure web app one ASPNETCORE WebAPI with Swagger and it is working well. But, my API do some upload of the file to one folder. When I try to access the uploaded files through the URL, the application redirects me to the Swagger home. So I can't access the uploaded files. How can I fix it?

For example:
My API URL is

```
http://api.guarda.digital/swagger/
```

the uploaded file is at

```
http://api.guarda.digital/uploads/1535281344287289147145.jpg
```

If you access the file url, you'll be redirected to the swagger home.

Here is my `Startup.cs` configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Guarda Digital API", Version = "v1" });
            });                                                                                    
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseMvc();

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Guarda Digital API V1");
            });

             app.Run(async (context) => await Task.Run(() => context.Response.Redirect("/swagger")));
        }
```

And the `web.config` file located inside `/site/wwwroot`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\GD.WebAPI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because of that line

```
app.Run(async (context) => await Task.Run(() => context.Response.Redirect("/swagger")));
```

Remove that and redirects will not happen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As alsami noted, the redirection happens because of the line that does the response redirect to swagger for any requests not handled elsewhere.

However, you need to add

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

to enable the serving of static files, such those uploaded.

(Security note.  Please be sure to carefully limit the types and sizes of uploaded files if you are going to be serving them to the public.)

Comment: Thanks, but even using this method I'm still not able to reach any kind of files, such as jpg, png, txt and others. Do you have any idea of configuration I'm that could may missing?

Comment: You need to be sure that the content root path matches the folder you believe it does.  Try reviewing this blog post for more troubleshooting help.  https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html